# What's the static IP address, subnet mask, etc, for VMware Player

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, arch-linux, vmware-player, wired-networking

I'm trying to set up Arch Linux in VMware player. I set up the player so that it automatically connected the guest to the internet, and it worked (I could download the packages needed for install, `ping` domains, etc). However, after I finished installing Arch and restarted the guest, it wasn't automatically connected anymore. On the wiki it says to connect to a network via a wired connection (which VMware emulated) in Arch, you need the Static IP address, Subnet Mask bits, the Gateway IP Address, the Name Servers' IP Addresses, and Domain Name (for the latter it says you won't need it on a local LAN). How can I find what these are for my VM? Is there a setting somewhere? What are the defaults?